# Applying one step of Richardson's Extrapolation

Tags: numerical-methods

Suppose $N(h)$ is an approximation for every $h>0$ and that $M=N(h)+Ah^{4/3}+Bh^{7/3}$. Apply one step of Richardson's Extrapolation with Value $N(3h)=2.7172$ and $N(h)=2.7182$ and compute the impoved value for $M$. If needed take $h=.0001$.

I'm not really sure how to proceed, any help or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the $M$ equartion with $h$ and $3h$ and eliminate $A$.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, when you are approximating a quantity $M$ by a formula like
$$
M = N(h) + A h^{k_0} + B h^{k_1}, \quad k_1>k_0
$$

the extrapolation based on $N(h)$ and $N(h/t)$ is given by
$$
R(h,t)=\dfrac{t^{k_0} N(h/t)-N(h)}{t^{k_0}-1}
$$

This corresponds, as it was pointed out in one of the comments to use the "M" equations and eliminate the constant $A$.

In your case, the extrapolated value would be
$$
\frac{3^{4/3}N(h) - N(3h)}{3^{4/3}-1}\approx 2.7185
$$

Comment: Thank you. I managed to figure it out but its nice to see I got the right answer.